# Pointer to a pointer dereference

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I am learning C language and actually stopped at some maybe obvious problem.

```
void allocateArray(int **arr, int size, int value) {
    *arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if(*arr != NULL) {
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            *(*arr+i) = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Caller:

```
int *vector = NULL;
allocateArray(&vector,5,45);
```

This is code from *Understanding and Using C Pointers*. The problem is that I can't imagine how this line works:

```
*(*arr+i) = value;
```

to be more precisely, I don't know why we need to use 2 dereferencing stars instead of just writing `(*arr+i) = value;`

It would be nice to get some better example of how and why it should be like that.

Comment: What is `int **ar`? What do the two asterisks together mean?

Comment: It would be much much easier if you wrote int* p = malloc (size * sizeof (int)); *arr = p; and from then on use p instead of *arr.

Comment: @PM77-1 It's a pointer to a pointer to int. 
You are right gnasher729. It's now easy when I understand it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know why we need to use 2 dereferencing stars instead of just writing `(*arr+i) = value;`

Since `arr` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, `*arr+1` is a pointer to an `int`. You need a double pointer so that you could change the vale of the variable from inside a function call.

The general rule is if you need to change a variable of type `sometype` inside a function, you need to pass `sometype*` into the function, and use an additional asterisk inside to make assignments. Otherwise, changes that you make to parameter inside the function will remain local to the function. In this case, `sometype` is itself a pointer (i.e. `int*`) so in order to modify it inside `allocateArray` you need to pass `int**`.

Note: in C you do not need to cast `malloc`, so the second line of code can be rewritten like this:

```
*arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Actually I've got it just after I posted the question, but thank you for your answer. I think it is good to explain own problem to yourself because you can solve it easier :)